# Zend Framework, getParams -> setParams

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new with Zend Framework but i didn't find solution yet. Problem is next:
I have form, when is submitted user goes to index controller and there is an add action. I know how i can get params, This is what i want do:

```
$clear = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
foreach ($clear as $key => $value) {
    $clear[$key]=trim(strip_tags($value));
}
$this->setRequest()->setParams($clear);//error, Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Action::setRequest() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract
```

So question is how to change in whole page that params, so if i want anywhere access that data i could be sure that they are safe. And is it possible to change that params only to index controller. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change setRequest() to getRequest().

```
 $this->getRequest()->setParams($clear);
```

Comment: :) Thanks, why I didn't tried that :) This is exactly what i want!!! And thanks all on advices. Anyone know some nice tutorials to start with zend framework, books, etc i would be grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Zend_Filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) for validating and filtering user input. I think it's bad practice to alter the request parameters if you're only going to save data in your model. Instead, let Zend_Filter_Input take care of it and feed the result to your model.

What if you were to forward to another controller action? You wouldn't have access to the unaltered content. And when someone else buds in your project he/she might not expect the request parameters to have been altered.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm learning and switching from procedural to OOP approach. I'm just learning and want have control on everything that doing, but will follow your advice! ("change in whole page that params","And is it possible to change that params only to index controller"). "What if you were to forward to another controller action", because of that i didn't know can i _forward that data or... :) Thanks!

Comment: Zend Framework has a bit of a steep learning curve and when new to OOP it can be a bit overwhelming. Most of it can be found in the documentation though, it just takes some time to learn it :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$clear = $request->getParams();
foreach ($clear as $key => $value) {
    $clear[$key]=trim(strip_tags($value));
}
$request->setParams($clear);
```

In other words, you don't want to replace the request (with `setRequest()`) but merely replace the params with `setParams()`.

Comment: Thanks, I know I could do that, but was interested in manipulating params in framework... Thanks!

Comment: I was wrong, it's almost same, only i wanted to same object change properties... What i mean that i know is make new object and add some properties... :)